# jquery datatables fnGetNodes doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I have a datatable with a checkbox on the first column by each row, it means that it's like a checkboxColumn. Then, I want to get all checked rows, but the "**fnGetNodes**" function doesn't return all rows, it just returns the visible rows. 
**The datatable** reflects **user rolls** (Company access, Area access, Department Access, etc.), when I open a dialog to modify one of them (Ex: Area Access) and pick I.T., I close the dialog and go back to datatable in question (user rolls table). When I try to get all checked roll (in case I've deleted another one), fnGetNodes returns just visible rows, not all rows.
Here's code lines:

```
data = [];    
$($('table', "div#example").dataTable({ bRetrieve: true }).fnGetNodes()).find(":checkbox:checked").each(function (i, o) {
      data.push($(o).val());
});
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have invisible rows?

Comment: Cause I'm using pagination and filter, and according to datatables.net , fnGetNodes() must return all rows or data (fnGetData).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? With the checkboxes I mean

Comment: Get all the checked checkboxes

Comment: And thus get its respective values

Comment: I've looked into this there doesn't to be a clean way of doing this. Are each of the checkboxes values unique? I think there's a way around this

Comment: In fact, the checkboxColumn's value is primary key

Comment: Check the solution I have for you below

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what I have and I think is a lil neat.

where `.cb` is the class assigned to all checkboxes.

```
$('body').on('click', 'table tr .cb', function(){
    var value = $(this).val(),
        isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'),
        index = arr.indexOf(value);

    if (isChecked && index === -1) { // add to array if it doesn't exist in there already
        arr.push(value);
    } else if (!isChecked && index !== -1){ // if value exists in array and checkbox in unchecked, remove it from the array
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/8YttQ/)**

Comment: Sorry, that's not that I want. Thing is I can't get all checkboxes if I can't get all rows

Comment: Then why not just select the table rows like so `$('body').find('table tr')`

Comment: Cause that just take visible rows. Remember that jQuery datatables don't hide rows, it removes them.

Comment: True. The only other way is to get the checked boxes when the table is being created, provided the checkboxes are preselected.

Comment: Yes, but if loose the scope again, it will be a disaster again